# In Vim, how can I compile a .java file in /src/ and run its class file from /bin/?

Tags: java, vim

I'm using Windows, and my _vimrc file has the following lines:

```
autocmd Filetype java set makeprg=javac\ -d\ %:~:h:s?src?bin?\ %
set errorformat=%A%f:%l:\ %m,%-Z%p^,%-C%.%#
map <F9> :make<Return>:copen<Return>
map <F10> :cprevious<Return>
map <F11> :cnext<Return>
map <F12> :!start cmd /k "java %:~:s?src?bin?:r"
```

I just want to use this for quick editing, and I will be using an IDE most of the time, thus the need for the classic /src/ and /bin/ folders (they are at the same folder level).

So it happens like this:
- I open the .java file that I want to edit in vim (it is in the /src/ folder)
- I hit F9 and javac runs on my current file (%) and puts the class files in the /bin/ folder (this seems to work as expected), and a new error window is opened in vim to display compile errors
- I hit F10/F11 to cycle between errors
- I hit F12 to open a command prompt and execute the java program (I think I have to open the command prompt because my program asks for user input in the console), **except it gives an error in the command prompt that it could not find or load the main class**

I don't know why it won't work, the class paths seem correct.  Can you show me where I have went wrong?

**Edit:** @merlin2011 led me to the following answer:
`map <F12> :!start cmd /k "cd %:~:h:s?src?bin? & java %:r"`
I had to cd to /bin/ and then run java.

**Or:** without changing directory, and just changing the classpath:
`map <F12> :!start cmd /k "java -classpath %:~:h:s?src?bin? %:r"`

Comment: I'm not on Windows so I can't test this, but I believe you need to first `cd` to the directory `bin` directory and run the java command from there.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, thank you!  You should add that as an actual answer to reap the sweet upvotes, and so it won't look unanswered anymore.  I used `map <F12> :!start cmd /k "cd %:~:h:s?src?bin? & java %:r"`

Comment: You should only need to set the class path to the bin folder with the `-classpath <path_to_bin>` option.

Comment: @FDinoff  That works too, thanks.  `map <F12> :!start cmd /k "java -classpath %:~:h:s?src?bin? %:r"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For permanency, I am converting my comment into an answer.

In order run the Java command from `vim`, one must first `cd` to the directory `bin` and run the Java command from there.

```
 map <F12> :!start cmd /k "cd %:~:h:s?src?bin? & java %:r"
```